# This Show/Hide function isn't working with MultiSelect elements

Tags: jquery, show-hide, multi-select

This Show/Hide function works correctly with Select elements, but it stops working when I change them to MultiSelect elements (multiple="multiple") and/or add square brackets to the element's name (necessary for submitting the MultiSelect form elements to a db). How can I change it so that it will work with MultiSelect elements?

A working example is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/yaq5F/8/

*JS*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#row1, #row2").hide();
    if ($("[name=item1]").val() === "Null" || $("[name=item1]").val() === "") {
        $("#row1").show();
    } else {
        $("#row2").show()
    };
});
```

*HTML*

```
<div id=row1 style="font-weight:bold">Row 1 - Nothing selected</div>
<div id=row2 style="font-weight:bold; display:none;">Row 2 - Something selected</div>

<select name=item1 class="field">
<option value="Null">Select</option>
<option value=1>Option 1</option>
<option value=2>Option 2</option>
<option value=3>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `multiple` option, the returned value is an array, not a string since you can select multiple values by holding down the control key.

You might want to check the value with something like `$.inArray("Null", $(".field").val())`

---

For future reference, it really helps to just look and see what the value coming back is.  A simple `console.log($(".field").val())` is all I did to see what was going on.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out where to insert that code. Would you mind showing me how I would add it to my sample code?

Comment: Sure --> http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMBarr/yaq5F/11/ - Just keep in mind that having "Select" as the first item really doesn't make sense any more when the `multiple` attribute is added.  You may want to do something different.

Comment: Thank you :-D I'm using this with several multiselect elements which are pre-selected based on values fetched from the db. Is there a way to do this using the element's names, or do I need to use an id/class?

Comment: sure, you can select items with jQuery like like you would in CSS.  `$("select[name='item1']")` is probably what you're looking for.  Also, please mark my answer as correct if it helped you out :)

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't being clear. I was asking how I can incorporate it into my existing function which is already doing that :-) $("[name=item1]").val() === "Null" || $("[name=item1]").val() === "")

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Please update your JSFiddle example and I can take a look.

Comment: Did you see the link I posted earlier? Here it is again --> http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisMBarr/yaq5F/11/ <-- if you are using the `multiple` attribute you do it this way. If you are not, do it the way you had already.  If you need to do a mixture of BOTH, that's a different story.

Comment: I would like to do a mixture of both, if that's possible :-)